# React useEffect renders change on 2nd click?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a NavBar component and I want certain items on the NavBar to be left off when one of the other selections is chosen.

It works somewhat. The problem is that the elements that should disappear require a second click.
I want them to disappear from the menu selections with the first click.

I am missing something with useEffect. Am I trying to do something that is a little more complex than my solution is attempting?

**Snippet is not working properly**

```js
const { React, ReactDOM, PropTypes, w3color } = window
const { useEffect, useState, useRef } = React
const { render } = ReactDOM
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
const rootNode = document.getElementById('app')

const NavBar = (props) => {
const [menustatus, changeMenusStatus] = useState(null)

const changeContext = async (input) => {
    // console.log(input)
    changeMenusStatus(input)
  }

return (
    <>
    <h1><ReactLogo />Base React App for Testing Development</h1>
    <span>
    </span>
      <nav>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select1">Selection 1</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select2">Selection 2</NavLink>
          {menustatus !==  'restrict' && (
            <>
            <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select3">Selection 3</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select4">Selection 4</NavLink>
            </>
            )
          }

        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/restrict" onClick={() => changeContext('restrict')}>RESTRICT</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/about">About</NavLink>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  <div className="container">
    <NavBar />
  </div>
}

render(<App />, rootNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

**The Problem:**
The issue is that it takes 2 clicks for the NavBar to re-render without the excluded items. I want the excluded items not to appear when the selected link navigates to the proper page.

NavBar.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Nav.css'
import ReactLogo from '../ReactLogo/ReactLogo'

```
const Nav = (props) => {
  const [menustatus, changeMenusStatus] = useState(null)
  const NavContext = React.createContext("")
  console.log(`[Nav context] = ${props.navcontext}`)

  const changeContext = async (input) => {
    console.log(input)
    changeMenusStatus(input)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (menustatus) {
      console.log(menustatus)
    } else {
      console.log(`menustatus not set.`)
    }
  }, [menustatus]);

  return (
    <>
    <h1><ReactLogo />Base React App for Testing Development</h1>
    <span>
    </span>
    <NavContext.Provider value={menustatus}>
      <nav>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select1">Selection 1</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select2">Selection 2</NavLink>
        <NavContext.Consumer>
          {(context) =>
            (context ==='restrict') ? null
            :
            <>
            <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select3">Selection 3</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select4">Selection 4</NavLink>
            </>
          }
        </NavContext.Consumer>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/restrict" onClick={() => changeContext('restrict')}>RESTRICT</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/about">About</NavLink>
      </nav>
    </NavContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import Home from './screens/Home/Home'
import About from './screens/About/About';
import ScreenOne from './screens/ScreenOne/ScreenOne'
import ScreenTwo from './screens/ScreenTwo/ScreenTwo'
import ScreenThree from './screens/ScreenThree/ScreenThree'
import ScreenFour from './screens/ScreenFour/ScreenFour'
import ScreenFive from './screens/ScreenFive/ScreenFive'
import PersonList from './components/PersonList/PersonList'

class App extends Component {
  state = {people: []}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home navcontext="one" />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About navcontext="one" />} />
          <Route path="/select1" element={<ScreenOne navcontext="one" />} />
          <Route path="/select2" element={<ScreenTwo navcontext="two" />} />
          <Route path="/select3" element={<ScreenThree navcontext="three" />} />
          <Route path="/select4" element={<ScreenFour navcontext="four" />} />
          <Route path="/restrict" element={<ScreenFive navcontext="restrict" />} />
        </Routes>
        <PersonList people={this.state.people} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the issue, specifically? Update the `menustatus` state and log it in the `useEffect` hook after it had updated? BTW, you will want to use `React.useRef` hook instead of `createRef` for the `NavContext` so it's not recreated each render cycle. Maybe that is the issue? I don't know why you are using a context here though when regular React state is suitable.

Comment: The issue is that it takes 2 clicks for the NavBar to re-render without the excluded items.
I want the excluded items not to appear when the selected link navigates to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are declaring the `NavContext` context each render cycle inside the `Nav` component. If you need to use a React Context then be sure to declare it ***outside*** any React component.

I don't see the point in using a React Context here though when you can just conditionally render the menu items on the `menustatus` state locally.

Example:

```
const Nav = (props) => {
  const [menustatus, changeMenusStatus] = useState(null);

  const changeContext = (input) => {
    console.log(input);
    changeMenusStatus(input);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (menustatus) {
      console.log(menustatus);
    } else {
      console.log(`menustatus not set.`);
    }
  }, [menustatus]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        <ReactLogo />
        Base React App for Testing Development
      </h1>
        
      <nav>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/">Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select1">Selection 1</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select2">Selection 2</NavLink>
        {menustatus !== 'restrict' && (
          <>
            <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select3">Selection 3</NavLink>
            <NavLink className="navitem" to="/select4">Selection 4</NavLink>
          </>
        )}
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/restrict" onClick={() => changeContext('restrict')}>RESTRICT</NavLink>
        <NavLink className="navitem" to="/about">About</NavLink>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-useeffect-renders-change-on-2nd-click]

Comment: React.Context is overkill eh?

Comment: @KenIngram I wouldn't exactly call it overkill, per se, but just not quite the appropriate use case in this exact scenario.

Comment: Ok. Do you think it is contributing to the problem I am having by using it this way?

Comment: @KenIngram It's certainly not helping.

Comment: @KenIngram Oh, yes, thank you. Sorry if that caused any confusion.

Comment: I did it with the conditional render but it still requires two clicks on RESTRICT to activate the proper results. I'm not sure why that is part of the happening.

Comment: @KenIngram Bootstrap is weird to work with since it uses classes and direct DOM interaction and tends to do stuff *outside* the React lifecycle. Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244416/discussion-between-ken-ingram-and-drew-reese).

Comment: @KenIngram I've added a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-useeffect-renders-change-on-2nd-click-vryx1o) to my answer. Feel free to fork it and add in more of your code to see if you can reproduce the issue. If you can repro, share a link to your sandbox for us to take a look at.